# Standalone Table Type vs Table Type inside a package

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any advantage of using standalone table type vs the table type we create inside package spec or body in terms of efficiencies apart from below differences:

1. Standalone Table Type can be used in multiple places. Package table type can be used inside the package. Some may argue that we can create a common package spec and use the table type from package spec.
2. additional db object to maintain for standalone table type

Comment: You canot use package types in SQL code. For example `cast(<expression> as <package>.<type>)`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like this for example

```
type some_type is table of number;
```

then storing it in a separate package can help you to keep it together with another logically related objects. And giving access to those objects will be easier because you don't need to specify each object but just give access to the package.

And keeping it private for a package as you've mentioned in 1. can also be a reason why one can deside for using a package

Answer (score 0):

Some operations require the type defined as global type, e.g.

```
 select ...
 into ....
 from TABLE(<your table type variable>);
```

does not work with locally defined type (at least this was the case in earlier Oracle versions)